# Интеграция Tilda i Client ID

Tags: javascript, crm

Всем привет. Стоит задача интегрировать в скрытое поле тильды гугл Client ID - перелопатив пол интернета я так и не нашел способ внедрить в скрытое поле это значение.

В чем суть. Данные с тильды отправляются в CRM, тильда при этом отправляет все куки пользователя в которых и содержится GCI - в интернете нашел такой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var needCookieName = '_ga';
var needCookieValue = '';
var needVarName = '_ga';
var value = "; " + document.cookie;
var parts = value.split("; " + needCookieName + "=");
if (parts.length == 2) needCookieValue = parts.pop().split(";").shift();
$('form.js-form-proccess').each(function(){
    $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="'+needVarName+'" value="'+needCookieValue+'">');
});
```

});

Подключил код к тильде и в скрытое поле поставил значение _ga

Однако после анализа через веб хуки - эти данные все ровно не передаются. Подскажите где копать или ссылку на скрипт пожалуйста.